# How to achieve pagination and sorting for object from api response in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an object from API response which is random key value pair.

```
{
name1:value1;
name2:value2;
......
}
```

How to add pagination for this? I can't use mat-paginator and mat-sort here I guess.I tried using PageEvent class. But that is not something I'm looking for.

Till now I have done this
app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  displayedColumns=['key','value'];
  initialDataSource={};
  lowValue: number = 0;
  highValue: number = 20;
  length:number;
  pageIndex:number;
  pageSize:number;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  RenderDataTable() {  
    this.apiService.GetAllRecords().subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(res);
    this.initialDataSource=new MatTableDataSource();
    this.initialDataSource=res;
    console.log(this.initialDataSource);
  });  
} 
  constructor(public apiService:ApiService, public http: HttpClient){

  }
  applyFilter(event: Event){
    .......    
  }
  public getPaginatorData(event: PageEvent): PageEvent {
    this.lowValue = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
    this.highValue = this.lowValue + event.pageSize;
    return event;
  }
  public refreshlist=()=>{
    window.location.reload();
  }
  ngOnInit(){
   this.RenderDataTable();

  } 
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource | keyvalue | 
slice: lowValue : highValue"  >

  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Key </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator 
[length]="length"
pageSize=5
(page)="getPaginatorData($event)"
[pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
showFirstLastButtons="false">
</mat-paginator>
```

api.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });  
  _baseUrl: string = '';  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this._baseUrl = "https://beta.randomapi.com/api/3141b5683af0edf576dabdb50ef1ff64?fmt=prettyraw&sole"; 
   }
   public GetAllRecords() {  
    return this.http.get(this._baseUrl);  
  }  
}
```

This issue is solved now ....Thank you

Comment: Can the user sort the columns ? Can he use filters ? Do you plan to implement those functionalities in the future ?

Comment: yes the user should be able to sort the columns and use filters . But how do I implement sort and pagination functionalities in this case?

Comment: It's more complicated in this case. You seem to have found correct librairies to do this so what is your problem exactly? You can't get those to work? What is the error?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jymg7m

Comment: Yes I can't get those to work..so I tried something else. But that's not exactly what I want. The user must be able to sort the rows..and pagination does not work until user has interacted with paginator component because I have used an event there..